# Make java string appear in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, web

I'm sure this sounds like a noob question to some of you but this isn't something I do every day. I want to print a java string userName in a jsp page. is there a tutorial or simple example I could follow in order to do that?

Comment: This depends on context. If `userName` is a request attribute, simply use EL with `${userName}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<%=userName%> or ${userName}

Comment: you know, I'll take it since nobody likes this question. thanks